# How to pass access token in Angular Js Post method

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I am trying to create user roles by using email id and role , in headers i am passing content type and authorization, when i submit the form i am getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load error. How to pass the authorization token in angualr js.

```
var Access_Token = L5uCp_JwSa9Fk7_ShrqPWi1FPdT_.......

$http({ 
url: "http://localhost:54581/api/Account/AddRole?username=" + email +  "&Role=User",
 method: "POST",
 headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Access_Token
                    }

                }).
                then(function (response) {
                    alert("Success")
                })
```

Comment: try adding a data field in request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST method, then you cant append params to the url directly. You need to first serialise it using the angular's inbuilt httpParamSerializer and send it in the data.

```
var myData = {username : email,Role : "user"}
$http({
    url: http://localhost:54581/api/Account/AddRole,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Access_Token
    }
  });
```

Comment: still i am getting error  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54581/api/Account/AddRole?username=m@gmail.com&Role=User. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: What was the eror you were getting before?

Comment: Then probably some issue with your backend API. what are you using in the backend?

Comment: if i pass the same url and access token in postman its working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133532/discussion-between-bala-abhinav-and-srinivas-r).